# How to state the time for data in the certain region

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column in a table name Delivery_Time, the format for it is like
5/10/2016 10:20:30 AM;
For some reason, I need the yesterday data, usually you can state:
trunc(delivey_date)=trunc(sysdate)-1;
But for this report, I need it give me the data where the time greater than yesterday 1 AM and less than today 1 AM; I am trying to say:

```
TRUNC(A.delivery_DATE) between trunc(sysdate)-1+(1/24) and trunc(sysdate)+(1/24)
```

But it does't work..can anyone give me some advice.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by doesn't work? use `A.delivery_DATE between trunc(sysdate)-1+(1/24) and trunc(sysdate)+(1/24)` because delivery_date is datetime. you shouldn't truncate when comparing with other datetimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `trunc` for `A.delivery_DATE`:

```
A.delivery_DATE between (trunc(sysdate) - 1 + (1/24)) and (trunc(sysdate) + (1/24))
```

Comment: Thanks, understood